# Bot sends embed message but doesn't send mp4 attachment

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

New to coding and recently started making a discord bot using JS. It's a bot where a certain mp4 plays with a specific snippet.

I'm having trouble with the fact that the mp4 doesn't send when I input the command, just the embed message. Basically if I do `-snip kratos` the bot sends the embed message but not the mp4.

Here's what I have so far:

````
const fs = require('fs');
const { Client, MessageAttachment } = require('discord.js');
const config = require('./config.json');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
const client = new Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();```


And here are the command events:

```  client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === `${prefix}snip kratos`) {
    if (message.author.bot) return
    const kratos = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#ffb638')
      .setTitle('Kratos')
      .setDescription('Sending 1 snippet(s)...')
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter('SkiBot');
      message.channel.send(kratos);
      client.on('message', message => {
        if (message.content === `${prefix}snip kratos`) {
          if (message.author.bot) return
          const attachment = new MessageAttachment('./snippets/kratos/Kratos.mp4');
          message.channel.send(attachment);

        }
      });
    }
    });

    client.on('message', message => {
      if (message.content === `${prefix}snip johnny bravo`) {
      if (message.author.bot) return
      const kratos = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#ffb638')
        .setTitle('Johnny Bravo')
        .setDescription('Sending 1 snippet(s)...')
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter('SkiBot');
        message.channel.send(kratos);
        client.on('message', message => {
          if (message.content === `${prefix}snip johnny bravo`) {
            if (message.author.bot) return
            const attachment = new MessageAttachment('./snippets/Johnny_Bravo/Johnny_Bravo.mp4');
            message.channel.send(attachment);

          }
        });
      }
      });```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are nesting event listeners. Remove the nested `client.on('message', ...)` part and send the message attachment after sending the embed.

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) {
    return
  }

  if (message.content === `${prefix}snip kratos`) {
    const kratos = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#ffb638')
      .setTitle('Kratos')
      .setDescription('Sending 1 snippet...')
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter('SkiBot')
    message.channel.send(kratos)
    const attachment = new MessageAttachment('./snippets/kratos/Kratos.mp4')
    message.channel.send(attachment)
  }
})
```

And you don't need multiple `message` event listeners. You can simplify the code by creating an object with the valid commands.

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  const { content, author, channel } = message
  if (author.bot) {
    return
  }

  const embeds = {
    [`${prefix}snip kratos`]: {
      title: 'Kratos',
      attachmentPath: './snippets/kratos/Kratos.mp4',
    },
    [`${prefix}snip johnny bravo`]: {
      title: 'Johnny Bravo',
      attachmentPath: './snippets/Johnny_Bravo/Johnny_Bravo.mp4',
    },
  }

  const embed = embeds[content]
  if (embed) {
    const { title, attachmentPath } = embed

    channel.send(
      new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#ffb638')
        .setTitle(title)
        .setDescription('Sending 1 snippet...')
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter('SkiBot')
    )
    channel.send(new MessageAttachment(attachmentPath))
  }
})
```

The above solution should be enough if you don't have a lot of commands. Check [this](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/#individual-command-files) guide to learn how to create individual command files to keep your code organized.

Comment: Hi, so I wanted to this but with multiple mp4's instead of one. I tried doing it the way you showed me but it didn't work.

Comment: @mega Can you share your code in a [GitHub Gist](http://gist.github.com/) or something?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/meremalice/19c47e9151b5fdd752ea275c69bb9463

Comment: @mega The issue is that you're overriding the value of `attachmentPath`. It should be an array. An example: `{ title: 'primadonna prod. umru', attachmentPaths: ['maddo.mp4', 'nna.mp4', 'pree.mp4'] }`. And then you can send the videos using `const { title, attachmentPaths } = embed; channel.send({ files: attachmentPaths }) `. Btw, you shouldn't nest the message event listeners. In fact, you don't need multiple message event listeners as I mentioned in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do

```
message.channel.send({
  files: [
    "./snippets/kratos/Kratos.mp4"
]})
```

As referred to here https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send

Also right here `client.commands = new Discord.Collection();` right here you are calling Discord but Discord was not defined